# How to add .flv video in magento CMS?

Tags: video, magento, flv

When i add .flv media using CMS in magento it shows white blank screen on flash player as option.
I am using 1.4.0.1 version of magento.

How do I add flash videos on static pages in magento.

Comment: Does the Flash Player load at all? Are the paths correct?

Answer (score 1):

The CMS in Magento doesn't include a video player, you need to supply a SWF flash object in it's place. There are a limited choice of extensions for providing video, I've never been impressed enough by any to recommend them.

When I need to I use the HTML button so I can paste in either the embed code from Youtube or my own choice of player, like [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/), which means knowing a little about the [media URL tag](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags#media_url).

Comment: Flowplayer is paid, and youtube doesn not allow to upload video more then 15 mins :( .

Comment: There is a free version of Flowplayer, admittedly with a logo on it, but there are also innumerable other FLV players out there, you only need to search for them.

Comment: Youtube allows over 15 min now.